# Code Igniter - Trying to get property of a non object

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

I am trying to implement cart functionality in codeigniter. In my controller I have a public function `add` and in my model a public function called `get` to fetch data from database according to the product selected.

here is my Controller

```
public function add() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $product = $this->products_model->get($id);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($product);  die();

    $data = array(
      'id' => $id,
      'name' => $product->pro_name,
      'qty' => 1,
      'price' => $product->pro_price
    );
    $this->cart->insert($data);
  }
```

and here is my Model

```
public function get($id) {
  $results = $this->db->get_where('products', array('pro_id' => $id));
  return $results->result_array();
}
```

When I `print_r($product)` I get an array like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [pro_id] => 1
            [pro_name] => Beef Carrot & Pea Food
            [pro_price] => 150.00
            [pro_image] => 1.png
        )

)
```

But when I try to insert in the data array I get this error.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/cart.php

Line Number: 11

Backtrace:

File: E:\xampp\htdocs\ci\dogschew\application\controllers\cart.php
Line: 11
Function: _error_handler

File: E:\xampp\htdocs\ci\dogschew\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Since u r using single item with object in your controller,So you should use `row()` instead of `result_array()`;*

Your model should be like this :

```
public function get($id) 
{
  $results = $this->db->get_where('products', array('pro_id' => $id));
  return $results->row();
}
```

Your controller should be like this :

*Print `$data` in your controller  to check it has data;*

```
public function add() 
{
     $id = $this->input->post('id');
     $product = $this->products_model->get($id);

     $data = array(
       'id' => $id,
       'name' => $product->pro_name,
       'qty' => 1,
       'price' => $product->pro_price
     );
     print_r($data); die();
     $this->cart->insert($data);
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

Comment: Partially solved. Now whenever I insert only data with even number ID values are getting inserted in the cart and not the odd number id values. Means values with 2,4,6,8 are getting inserted and 1,3,5,7 are not getting inserted. I have reached the question limit so can't raise a new one. If you can help by updating the answer it will be a great help.

Comment: without seeing your code unable to help you from this side may be some check are there

Comment: did it solve your current problem? is my answer helpful for you or not?

Comment: Yes it solved. And sorry the second problem was misintepreted. The problem is here. I asked a new question with another account plz check. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51150107/codeigniter-add-to-cart-does-not-insert-data-in-cart-array-where-name-has-a-spec?noredirect=1#comment89283847_51150107

Answer (score 0):

You need to access values using array syntax not object syntax

`$product->pro_name` instead of this use `$product['pro_name']`

Comment: Partially solved. Now whenever I insert only data with even number ID values are getting inserted in the cart and not the odd number id values. Means values with 2,4,6,8 are getting inserted and 1,3,5,7 are not getting inserted. I have reached the question limit so can't raise a new one. If you can help by updating the answer it will be a great help.

Comment: Copying and pasting this for every answer isn't going to help. Update your question with the relevant code. Bare in mind (for the future) it is considered bad form to change the question after the fact ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an array and not an object. Hence, `$product` will contain an array...

As the error says:

`Trying to get property of non-object`

Try this:

```
$data = [
    'id' => $id, 
    'name' => $product[0]['pro_name'], 
    'qty' => 1, 
    'price' => $product[0]['pro_price']
];
```

...or better yet, use `row()` method on your model's `get()` method, like so:

```
public function get($id)
{
    $results = $this->db->get_where('products', [
        'pro_id' => $id
    ]); 

    return $results->row();
}
```

Using that, you can now have:

```
$data = [
    'id' => $id, 
    'name' => $product->pro_name, 
    'qty' => 1, 
    'price' => $product->ipro_price
];
```

Source:
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-rows

Comment: Partially solved. Now whenever I insert only data with even number ID values are getting inserted in the cart and not the odd number id values. Means values with 2,4,6,8 are getting inserted and 1,3,5,7 are not getting inserted. I have reached the question limit so can't raise a new one. If you can help by updating the answer it will be a great help.

Comment: try to check your error logs to find some clues. i am suspecting duplicate record insertion error via `id` column if that's your primary key on `cart` table. can you show us your `cart` table structure?