# CodeIgniter Add to Cart does not insert data in Cart array where name has a special character

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to integrate add to cart in CodeIgniter. Now the problem is that whenever I try to add a data to the cart it only inserts data whose name in the database field does not have a special character and ignores data whose name in the database field has a special character. For example, if the product name coming from database is Jeans & Top it will ignore it whereas it will accept if it is Jeans Top instead. I tried using `&amp;` instead of & in the database but same problem. Do I need to escape it somewhere in the controller? If yes, how? I am new to CI. Please help me.

Controller:

```
public function add() {
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $product = $this->products_model->get($id);

    $data = array(
      'id' => $id,
      'name' => $product->pro_name,
      'qty' => 1,
      'price' => $product->pro_price,
    );
    // echo "<pre>";
    // print_r($data);

    if($this->cart->insert($data) == TRUE) {
      redirect('cart/show');
    } else {
      die('ERROR ADDING CART');
    }
  }
```

Model:

```
public function get($id) {
    $results = $this->db->get_where('products', array('pro_id' => $id));
    return $results->row();
  }
```

Comment: data type for column pro_name in cart table???

Comment: the data type is varchar

Comment: set `$product_name_safe` from `TRUE` to `TRUE` should be like this  `$product_name_safe = FALSE`

Answer (score 1):

Open your `Cart.php` file. Find for `var $product_name_rules`

Replace

`var $product_name_rules    = '\.\:\-_ a-z0-9';` with
`var $product_name_rules    = '[:print:]`

**you can find Cart.php from system/libraries/Cart.php**

Answer (score 0):

In `system/libraries/Cart.php`

`$product_name_safe = TRUE;`

replace

`$product_name_safe = FALSE;`